# Removing/disabling a span class across a whole html code using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just new to JQuery and am looking to use its functionality of removing span class in a html file. 
This is an example:

```
<p>Tatur mo commod ut ulluptataqui dolut accum, aut vendis simin rehenia que volestio eseria volo et eiusam, optaten dipiet hil id minctes nobis essit doluptibus et essint es ma volessi taspelibus. **<span class=’pagenum’><a name=”Page_7” id=”Page_7”>[Pg 7]</a></span>** Nam accus molendit estiae landuciis qui ipsa cus ea sunt ex et di blaccatest.</p>
```

I would like to remove such span strings having different numbers across the entire html at one go using JQuery. Is it possible to do so? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Aman Mittal

Comment: If I am not wrong then you want to remove all the span tags from your web page or website whatever it is.?

Comment: Do your homework, pour in your efforts, come back if you are stuck at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is not to show them at all, do this:
Note that this is CSS

```
span {display: none;}
```

If you want to have them hidden but take up their space,

```
span {opacity: 0}
```

You don't need jQuery to do that, however, you can add this style using jQuery, but that would be useless since you can do it with pure css

```
$(document).ready(function)(){
    $('span').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
$('p').find('span').remove();
```